# Capture a generic runtime type of an object in a function

Tags: dart

Consider the following minimal example:

```dart
class Element<T> {}

final elements = [
  Element<String>(),
  Element<int>(),
];

Element<T> transformation<T>(Element<T> element) => Element<T>();

void main() {
  // prints 'Element<String>', 'Element<int>'
  for (final element in elements) {
    print(element);
  }

  // prints 'Element<Object>', 'Element<Object>',
  // but I would like to get identical output as above.
  for (final element in elements) {
    print(transformation(element));
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how to create a transformation of each `Element<T>` with its respective generic runtime type `T`, not the static `Object` type of the `elements` collection.

I remember having seen some complicated trick with nested closures in the past, but can't seem to find it anymore. How can I make my function capture the runtime type of `T`, without having to implement the transformation function in the `Element` class itself?

Comment: I don't think that you can.  The static type of the `elements` is necessarily `Element<Object>`, and generic type parameters are also resolved statically, so `transformation()` will be `transformation<Object>()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible.
The only way to get access to the type variable of an object is if the object gives it to you.
If `Element` had a method like

```dart
  R callWith<R>(R Function<T>(Element<T>) action) => action<E>(this);
```

then you could get access to the `E` of `Element<E>` as a type variable.
You can't do that from outside the class.