# Getting a more specific generic type than dynamic

Tags: dart

Consider the following minimal example:

```dart
class Clazz<T> {}

Clazz<R> join<R, A extends R, B extends R>(Clazz<A> a, Clazz<B> b) => Clazz<R>();

void main() {
  final a = Clazz<int>();
  final b = Clazz<double>();

  print(a);  // 'Clazz<int>'
  print(b);  // 'Clazz<double>'
  print(join(a, b));  // 'Clazz<dynamic>', but would like 'Clazz<num>'
}
```

I would expect that calling `join` would return an instance of `Clazz` with the most specific generic type, yet Dart always infers `dynamic` as the generic type. I also tried without success with a static extension method (same problem) and with a method within the class itself (unable to specify type constraints). What can I do to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `join<R, A extends R, B extends R>`, `A extends R` and `B extends R` set *constraints* on what `A` and `B` can be.  The compiler will not compute the most specific common base type of `A` and `B` to infer `R`; it just needs to find *any* type `R` that satisfies the constraint.

`Clazz<int>` is a `Clazz<num>` (and likewise for `Clazz<double>`), so you can do what you want by simplifying `join` to remove the `A` and `B` types:

```dart
Clazz<R> join<R>(Clazz<R> a, Clazz<R> b) => Clazz<R>();
```

and now whe you call `join(a, b)`, the compiler will automatically find the most specific common base type of `Clazz<int>` and `Class<double>` to satisfy a common `Clazz<R>`.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the explanation. Wondering if there is a way to achieve the same with a single argument method either within `Clazz<T>` or as an static extension method on `Clazz<T>`?

Comment: I don't think that there is an easy way to do it as a class method or extension.

Comment: Is there any way? I am already in the territory where I resort to tricks like https://stackoverflow.com/a/66830882/82303 just to get a nice API that doesn't yield dynamic generics everywhere.